# Mapping one xml into another with xsl using python lxml

Tags: python, lxml

I have a xml whose data needs to be extracted into another xml in a different format. The fields to be mapped are provided by a xsl. I need to test if the xml transformation done by an application is correct using this xsl mapping. The xmls are very large running into GB sizes and hence i prefer using iterparse from python's lxml. How can i use lxml to map the 2 xmls with the mapping provided in the xsl?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong. You have source and resulting xml, xsl transformation file. You want to check if the resulting xml was made by this xsl transformation applied to the source xml. So, you can just make an xsl transformation of the source and see if the result has the same content as the resulting xml. Am I right?

Comment: Yes you are right but sometimes the files are so huge so I have 2 xmls trees and an xsl in memory and i get a Out of memory error